# why doesn't my downvote take?

Tags: support, status-norepro

tried to downvote a very bad answer.  it had already been downvoted once. my downvote seemed to make it -2, but when I ext and return it's still -1.  what am I missing?

update: now it seems to have taken.  software glitch?

Comment: Things like this may happen when the internet connection is slow, but it is impossible to tell what exactly happened. Is it important?

Comment: no, I think it must have been sth like what you mention.  spoke too soon, I guess.